# threejs orbitController Camera LookAt doesn't work

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm using threejs to develop an application. I apply OrbitControls to my camera. But for some reasons, I need sometimes to set manually the rotation of the camera. My problem is that the camera's `lookAt()` function doesn't work because it overrides the orbitController. I don't know how to do it, `Quaternion.lerp()` doesn't work also. I just need to set manually the rotation of the camera.

Comment: does the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn orbitcontrols off with `controls.enabled=false`

[Three.JS Orbit Controls - enabling and disabling without position jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596249/three-js-orbit-controls-enabling-and-disabling-without-position-jumping)

[Dragging and Clicking Objects with Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161674/dragging-and-clicking-objects-with-controls)